# How to extract href from a tag using ruby regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, html-parsing

I have this link which i declare like this:

```
link = "<a href=\"https://www.congress.gov/bill/93rd-congress/house-bill/11461\">H.R.11461</a>"
```

The question is how could I use regex to extract only the href value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use a regular expression like this:

```
href\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"
```

See [this Rubular example](http://rubular.com/r/U60oZLkFan) of that expression.

The capture group will give you the URL, e.g.:

```
link = "<a href=\"https://www.congress.gov/bill/93rd-congress/house-bill/11461\">H.R.11461</a>"
match = /href\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"/.match(link)
if match
  url = match[1]
end
```

#### Explanation of the expression:

- `href` matches the href attribute
- `\s*` matches 0 or more whitespace characters (this is optional -- you only need it if the HTML might not be in canonical form).
- `=` matches the equal sign
- `\s*` again allows for optional whitespace
- `"` matches the opening quote of the href URL
- `(` begins a capture group for extraction of whatever is matched within
- `[^"]*` matches 0 or more non-quote characters. Since quotes inside HTML attributes must be escaped this will match all characters up to the end of the URL.
- `)` ends the capture group
- `"` matches the closing quote of the href attribute's value

Answer (score 8):

If you want to parse HTML, you can use the [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) gem instead of using regular expressions. It's much easier.

Example:

```
require "nokogiri"

link = "<a href=\"https://www.congress.gov/bill/93rd-congress/house-bill/11461\">H.R.11461</a>"

link_data = Nokogiri::HTML(link)

href_value = link_data.at_css("a")[:href]

puts href_value # => https://www.congress.gov/bill/93rd-congress/house-bill/11461
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to capture just the url you can do this:

```
/(href\s*\=\s*\\\")(.*)(?=\\)/
```

And use the second match.

http://rubular.com/r/qcqyPv3Ww3